# Fast evaluation of polynomials

Tags: cryptanalysis

Let $x_1,\dots,x_n$ and $y_1,\dots,y_N$ be some known integers modulo $2^k$, where $n\ll N$.

For each $x_i$, I have the following polynomial:

$$P_i(z)= \prod_{j=0}^{k-1}(z+2^jx_i) \mod 2^k.$$

Note that these polynomials are sparse, because only high powers of $z$ survive the coefficient-wise reduction.

My objective is to find the values of $y_1,\dots,y_N$ that vanish each of these polynomials, i.e., find the zeroes among $P_i(y_j)$ for $i\leq n, j\leq N$.

The naive approach of (perform every evaluation) is obviously on $O(knN)$ products in this ring of integers. Is there any way to do better, considering the form of these polynomials and the fact that they are sparse?

Comment: And what does this question have to do with cryptography?

Comment: Hello, evaluation of polynomials is widely used in cryptanalysis. As is sparse algebra. These polinomials arise in some resultant computations related to RSA modulus, I did not think putting the whole context matters, but I could certainly give more details.

Comment: For $x_i$ even, the zeros of $P_i$ are exactly all even numbers. For $x_i$ odd and any $z$, there is exactly one of the terms $z+2^jx_i$ even and all other terms are odd (i.e., invertible mod $2^k$). Therefore $z$ is a zero of $P_i$ if and only if the even term $z+2^jx_i$ is already 0 mod $2^k$.

Comment: Thanks for the insight. To find which among the $t$ vanishes the polynomial I could proceed as you say and compute all the combinations. I was wondering if, given the sparsity of the polynomials, was it faster to use some fast evaluation algorithm on these polynomials.

Comment: Somewhat similar polynomial representation was used for sets and graphs, including 2008/363 IACR preprint. The difference is, polynomials are relatively prime there, 1-to-1 correspondence to sets and graphs, an upper bound on number of root. Interactive proofs with "large" (not binary) challenges were designed for graph isomorphism, hamiltonicity, colorability, as well as a SNARK circuit for Sudoku, all starting from such a polynomial representation.

Comment: What do you mean with $t$ in your comment? And I don't understand from the formulation of your question, if you want to get (1) for every $j\le N$ the set of $i\le n$ such that $P_i(y_j)=0$ or (2) the set of $j\ne N$ such that $P_i(y_j)=0$ for all $i\le n$.

Comment: Sorry it was a typo. I meant the $y_j$, not $t$.

Comment: I only need to find every pair $(i,j)$ such that $P_i(y_j)=0$. That is, the roots of the $P_i$'s among the set of $y$'s. Otherwise said, the intersection between the algebraic variety formed by the $P$'s and the set of $y$'s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can find the pairs $(i,j)$ with $P_i(y_j)=0$ in time $N\cdot\log(N)$ for preprocessing and $k\cdot n\cdot\log(N)$ for processing, if you can use space $N$ for preprocessing the $y_i$:

Preprocessing consists of generating (1) the list $E$ of all $j$ such that $y_j$ is even, and (2) a tree (or something even faster) that you can query in time $\log(N)$ for a given $y$ to get the list of all $j$ such that $y=y_j$.

Now loop over all $x_i$, adding to the result either (1) all indices $(i, e)$ for $e\in E$ if $x_i$ is even or (2) all $(i, j)$ with $y_j = -x_i\cdot 2^l \bmod 2^k$ for some $l\le k$ (using the precomputed tree) if $x_i$ is odd.

The reason why this gives the correct result is written in my first comment to your question.